# Index inside map() function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutable.js

I am missing a option how to get the index number inside the `map` function using `List` from `Immutable.js`:

`var list2 = list1.map(mapper => { a: mapper.a, b: mapper.index??? }).toList();`

[Documentation shows](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/map) that `map()` returns `Iterable<number, M>`. Is there any elegant way to what I need?

Comment: Keep in mind that `map` is supposed to preserve the structure of the array that is, only its values should be transformed not the array itself.

Comment: Array.prototype.map() create a new array using the callback function as transformation

Answer (score 1015, accepted):

You will be able to get the current iteration's `index` for the `map` method through its 2nd parameter.

**Example:**

```js
const list = [ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
list.map((currElement, index) => {
  console.log("The current iteration is: " + index);
  console.log("The current element is: " + currElement);
  console.log("\n");
  return currElement; //equivalent to list[index]
});
```

**Output:**

```
The current iteration is: 0 <br>The current element is: h

The current iteration is: 1 <br>The current element is: e

The current iteration is: 2 <br>The current element is: l

The current iteration is: 3 <br>The current element is: l 

The current iteration is: 4 <br>The current element is: o
```

**See also:** https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

> **Parameters**
>
> callback - 
>     Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking three arguments:
>
> 1) currentValue
>         The current element being processed in the array.
>
> **2) index
>
>       The index of the current element being processed in the array.**
>
> 3) array
>       The array map was called upon.

Comment: Should the map's callback function always have a return statement? What does 'X' mean in your code?

Comment: @HarshKanchina The `map` operation is use for constructing a new array by iterating through the elements of a given array. To answer your question, yes a return statement is required, and for this case it is returning the value 'X' on each iteration. Thus the final product of the code will be `[ 'X', 'X','X','X' ]`

Comment: @But 'X' isn't defined anywhere. So what is it referring to? How does the function know what X refers to here?

Comment: @HarshKanchina `'X'` is a string.

Comment: I want this index to start with 1, how could i achieve this?

Comment: @ReemaParakh You can use simple math for that, e.g.  `(index + 1)` like `console.log("The current iteration is: " + (index + 1));`

Comment: Having index as a second parameter is the Ruby way, and I mean it in the most positive way.

Comment: This answer explains native javascript arrays, while the question is about ImmutableJS. However, [not quite] _coincidentally_, the callback function has the same signature. While it links to the wrong docs, it unintentionally gives the correct answer

Answer (score 77):

### `Array.prototype.map()` index:

One can access the index `Array.prototype.map()` via the second argument of the callback function. Here is an example:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const map = array.map((x, index) => {
  console.log(index);
  return x + index;
});

console.log(map);
```

### Other arguments of `Array.prototype.map()`:

- The third argument of the callback function exposes the array on which map was called upon
- The second argument of `Array.map()` is a object which will be the `this` value for the callback function. Keep in mind that you have to use the **regular `function` keyword** in order to declare the callback since an arrow function doesn't have its own binding to the `this` keyword.

For example:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const thisObj = { prop1: 1 }

const map = array.map((x, index, array) => {
  console.log(array);
  console.log(this)
}, thisObj);
```

Answer (score 9):

- suppose you have an array like

```js
   const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    
    
    arr.map((myArr, index) => {
      console.log(`your index is -> ${index} AND value is ${myArr}`);
    })
```

```
> output will be
 index is -> 0 AND value is 1
 index is -> 1 AND value is 2
 index is -> 2 AND value is 3
 index is -> 3 AND value is 4
 index is -> 4 AND value is 5
 index is -> 5 AND value is 6
 index is -> 6 AND value is 7
 index is -> 7 AND value is 8
 index is -> 8 AND value is 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Ramda:

```
import {addIndex, map} from 'ramda';

const list = [ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
const mapIndexed = addIndex(map);
mapIndexed((currElement, index) => {
  console.log("The current iteration is: " + index);
  console.log("The current element is: " + currElement);
  console.log("\n");
  return 'X';
}, list);
```