# How to loop through this javascript and get the (id) and (brandName)

Tags: javascript, json

How to do i get the `id value` and `brandName value`

```
[{"id":24,"brandName":"BMW"},{"id":25,"brandName":"Mercedes Benz"}]
```

Comment: cant you get them with .id and .brandName?

Comment: what are you expecting as output?

Comment: how do i loop through? javascript

Comment: `arr.forEach(i => {console.log(i.id);console.log(i.brandName);})`

Comment: You have to use Javascript Array Map, The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.


Refer this links :

 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38364482/4270123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do as your question is very vague. But if you want to iterate over each element and do something with the values you could do something like this:

```
let items = [{"id":24,"brandName":"BMW"},{"id":25,"brandName":"Mercedes Benz"}];

items.forEach(elem => {
    const {id, brandName} = elem;
    console.log(`ID: ${id}. Brand Name: ${brandName}.`);
})
```

Comment: Error   uncaught TypeError: items.forEach is not a function

Comment: You need to pass in an array to use the .forEach.

Comment: JSON.parse(items).forEach(elem => {
        const {id, brandName} = elem;
    console.log(`ID: ${id}. Brand Name: ${brandName}.`);
    });