# Mapping through Array with JSX

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to `map` through a nested `Array` using `JSX`.

Here is the `Array`:

```
    this.topics = [

        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'first',
            headings : [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    url: 'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
                    name: 'Sintel movie'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    url: 'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4',
                    name: 'Bunny Movie'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    url: 'https://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
                    name: 'Test page'
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'second',
            headings : [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    url: 'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
                    name: 'Siddntel movie'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    url: 'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4',
                    name: 'Bunnddy Movie'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    url: 'https://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
                    name: 'Test ddpage'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

And the `JSX` code that I have come up with so far:

```
  renderSidenav(){
      return(
          <Nav>
              {this.topics.map(topic =>
                  <Dropdown eventKey="3" title="s" icon={<Icon icon="magic" />}>
                      {this.topics[topic].headings.map(heading =>
                          <div onClick = {() => this.handleSelect(heading.id)} key={heading.id}>
                              <Dropdown.Item style={{backgroundColor: '#E9F4E4'}} icon={<Icon icon="dashboard"/>}>
                                  <div>{heading.name}</div>
                              </Dropdown.Item>
                              <Dropdown.Item divider style={{backgroundColor: 'white', height: '2px'}}/>
                          </div>
                    )}
                  </Dropdown>
                )}
         </Nav>
      )
  }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headings' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.topics[topic]` isn't going to work because `topic` is an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index inside map() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364400/index-inside-map-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this.topics[topic].headings.map(...)` use `topic.headings.map(...)`

This is because `.map()` returns an object, and trying to use it as an index via `topics[topic]` will give you `undefined`.

Comment: I have no idea why i didn't try that but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `topic.headings.map` instead of `this.topics[topic].headings.map`.

Map function returns the item, not the position/index in the array, therefore you can call it directly from `topic`.