# How to convert for loop to map function

Tags: javascript

how to convert `model[i].bulkCreate(dtarr[i]);` to map function?

```
        const dtarr = [dataItems.Container_Type];
        const model = [Container]

        for (var i=0; i < model.length; i++) {
            model[i].bulkCreate(dtarr[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Please correct code formatting, and add question.

Comment: sorry for my formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index inside map() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364400/index-inside-map-function). I assume your problem is you don't know how to access the index of the collection you're iterating. Just use `.map((object, index) => object.bulkCreate(dtarr[index]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index argument of map function to get dtarr[index]

```
model.map((element, index) => element.bulkCreate(dtarr[index]));
```