# Point to the mapped id in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, array-map

I'm using the `map` function to iterate through an array in the `state`. My code is:

```
theList(){

    return  this.state.lists.map((list) => {
            return(
                <View style={this.state.listStatus[list.id].status?styles.list:styles.list2}>
                    <Text>{list.name}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        })

    }
```

How can I put the list.id in the `this.state.listStatus[here]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index inside map() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364400/index-inside-map-function)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two arrays with the same index and size (lists and listStatus), you might need this.

The second parameter of the map function is the iteration index.

```
theList(){

    return  this.state.lists.map((list, listIndex) => {
            return(
                <View style={this.state.listStatus[listIndex].status?styles.list:styles.list2}>
                    <Text>{list.name}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        })

    }
```