# sort items in state alphabetically

Tags: reactjs

I have a class based React component that is using items in state and rendering result. Here is short snippet how I do this:

```
class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: props.items.edges,
            someItems: props.items.edges,
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.items.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.state.someItems.map(({ node }) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={node.id}>
                                    <div>
                                        render some data
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The data is received as objects inside an array, like this:

[image]

My question is would it be possible to sort these items alphabetically before being rendered? What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Yes, you can sort it alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to sort the items before you set them to the state. You can use the built in [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method in order to sort the items. You can use the [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) in order to compare strings alphabetically.

I don't know the expected structure of your data so here is a general solution.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Make a copy so as not to modify the original array directly
        const sortedCopy = [...props.items];

        sortedCopy.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

        this.state = {
            items: sortedCopy,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.items.map((item) => (
                    <p key={item.id}>
                        <div>Item - {item.name}</div>
                    </p>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Example items prop is out of order
const items = [
    { id: 0, name: "C" },
    { id: 1, name: "B" },
    { id: 2, name: "A" },
    { id: 3, name: "D" },
];

ReactDOM.render(<App items={items} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great thank you Abir. That makes sense. My data more nested compared to yours. How would I map over this before sorting it, here is example of what one item in my array would look like: 

```const sortedCopy = [this.props.items.edges[0].node.title]```

Comment: I found "solution" to above comment, my data is quite nested so still trying to get my head around it. 

I found another post that explains this. Here is the article for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364400/index-inside-map-function