# Insert counter in a reactjs map

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to ReactJs and have a doubt when generating a list with an ordering. How do I include a counter inside my `map`?

The way I'm doing it is repeating the number 1 in all records. I wanted each record to have a counter (1 Adam, 2 Andrew, 3 Sophia ...)

```
<div>
  {
    data.contacts.data.map((contact) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span>1</span>  <b>{contact.data.name} {contact.data.email}</b>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364400/index-inside-map-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second argument (array index) of the [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
<div>
  {
    data.contacts.data.map((contact, index) => (
        <div>
          <span>{index + 1}</span>  <b>{contact.data.name} {contact.data.email}</b>
        </div>
      ))
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With map you have access to the index. So you can use the index to add a counter. Also, remember to add a key-value to each child you're printing with map (you can use the index for this).

```
<div>
  {
    data.contacts.data.map((contact, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <span>{index + 1}</span>  <b>{contact.data.name} {contact.data.email}</b>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
</div>
```